How to Dequeue and Re-Enqueue Elementor Frontend Styles with Lower Priority to Load Before Customizer Styles?
Could someone assist in dequeuing and re-enqueuing Elementor's frontend styles with a lower priority? Currently, these styles are loading with high priority, which is causing customizer styles embedded in the <head> tag to not take effect. I need the Elementor styles to load before the customizer styles so the customizer styles can properly override them. Please see the attached screenshot for reference.
I have been trying to dequeue Elementor’s frontend styles (elementor-frontend-css) and re-enqueue them with a lower priority. My goal is to make Elementor’s styles load earlier so that the Customizer styles (added within <head> by Kirki Framework) can properly override them.
I used the following approach to dequeue and re-enqueue the styles:
function adjust_elementor_frontend_css_priority() {
    // Dequeue Elementor frontend styles
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-frontend' );

    // Re-enqueue Elementor styles with a lower priority
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'elementor-frontend',
        plugins_url( 'elementor/assets/css/frontend.min.css' ),
        array(),
        ELEMENTOR_VERSION
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adjust_elementor_frontend_css_priority', 9999 );

